# Prove that $x^{-1} N_{G}(H) x = N_{G}(x^{-1}Hx).$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that:$$x^{-1} N_{G}(H) x = N_{G}(x^{-1}Hx).$$

Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Try to follow the definition, and show what you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following sequence of equivalent statements can be read from top to bottom or from bottom to top
$$
g \in N_G(x^{-1}Hx) \\
g^{-1}x^{-1}Hxg=x^{-1}Hx \\
xg^{-1}x^{-1}Hxgx^{-1} = H \\
xgx^{-1} \in N_G(H) \\
g \in x^{-1}N_G(H)x \\
$$

Comment: I think the in fourth step g instead of g^{-1}

Comment: you are right, thanks. will make the edit.